# Problem matching prices of Black-Scholes vs. GARCH(1,1) in Duan (1995)

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, monte-carlo, risk-neutral-measure, garch

In the paper of [Duan (1995)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9965.1995.tb00099.x#:%7E:text=the%20GARCH%20option%20pricing%20model%20is%20capable%20of%20reflecting%20the,with%20the%20Black%2DScholes%20model.) the author compare European call option prices using Black-Scholes model vs. GARCH(1,1)-M model (GARCH-in-mean). To be brief, the author fits the following GARCH(1,1)-M model

$$\ln(X_t/X_{t-1}) = r + \lambda \sqrt{h_t} - \frac{1}{2} h_t + \varepsilon_t $$
$$ \varepsilon_t |\phi_{t-1} \sim N(0,h_t) \quad \mbox{under measure P}  $$
$$ h_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \varepsilon_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 h_{t-1}  \tag{1}$$

to S&P 100 daily index series from `1986-01-02` to `1989-12-15`, where
$r$ is the risk-free interest rate, $\lambda$ is the constant unit risk premium and $\phi_t$ is the information set. For GARCH(1,1), $X_t$ and $h_t$ together serve as the sufficient statistics for $\phi_t$.

The author also provides the risk-neutral dynamics of (1) as follows
$$\ln(X_t/X_{t-1}) = r  - \frac{1}{2} h_t + \xi_t $$
$$ \xi_t |\phi_{t-1} \sim N(0,h_t) \quad \mbox{under measure Q}  $$
$$ h_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 (\xi_{t-1}-\lambda \sqrt{h_{t-1}})^2 + \beta_1 h_{t-1}  \tag{2}$$

They also state that the price of a European call option with exercise price $K$ is given by
$$C^{GH}_0 = e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^Q \bigg[ \max(X_T - K, 0) \bigg]$$
where the terminal asset price is derived as
$$X_T = X_0 \exp \bigg[rT -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{s=1}^T h_s + \sum_{s=1}^T \xi_s \bigg] \tag{3} $$

For the computation part, the author provides the estimated GARCH parameters and some other assumptions used in their calculations. Their assumptions and results are in the following R code

```r
#----------------------------------------------------
# information and results given by the author
#----------------------------------------------------
# estimated parameters of the GARCH(1,1)-M model
alpha0 <- 1.524e-05
alpha1 <- 0.1883
beta1 <- 0.7162
lambda <- 7.452e-03

r <- 0 # interest rate
K <- 1 # strike price is set at $1 (stated like this in the paper)
T2M <- c(30, 90, 180)  # days to maturity
S_over_K <-c(.8, .9, .95, 1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.2)  # moneyness ratios considered (stated like this in the paper)
Sigma <- 0.2413 / sqrt(365)

simulations <- 5*10^4  # Monte Carlo simulations

maturity <- c(rep(T2M[1], length(S_over_K)), rep(T2M[2], length(S_over_K)), rep(T2M[3], length(S_over_K)))
SK_ratio <- rep(S_over_K, length(T2M))

# Black-Scholes option prices
BS_price <- c(.1027, 18.238,89.79, 276.11, 600.41, 1027.9, 2001, 13.016, 118.54, 257.79, 478, 779.68, 1152.2, 2036.6, 66.446, 261.3, 438.17, 675.54, 970.49, 1318, 2133.4)

# GARCH prices when sqrt(h_1) = Sigma
GH_price <- c(.9495, 20.93, 86.028, 266.75, 596.13, 1030.2, 2003.5, 15.759, 116.06, 251.02, 468.9, 772.35, 1149.4, 2040.5, 68.357, 257.09, 431.7, 668.5, 964.29, 1313.9, 2134.7)

df <- data.frame(maturity, SK_ratio, BS_price, GH_price)
df
```

I'm trying to get their results by using the following code.

```r
#-------------------------------------------------------
# my attempt
#-------------------------------------------------------
library(rugarch)
library(stats)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(fOptions)
# download S&P100 daily index series
fromDate <- "1986-01-02"
toDate <- "1989-12-15"
quantmod::getSymbols("^OEX", from = fromDate, to = toDate)

# calculate the log returns
sp100ret <- na.omit(PerformanceAnalytics::CalculateReturns(OEX$OEX.Close, method = "log"))

# set GARCH(1,1)-M model specification
garchspec <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean=TRUE, archm=TRUE, archpow=1),
                        variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), 
                        distribution.model = "norm")
# fit the model to the daily returns data
sp100Fit <- ugarchfit(data = sp100ret, spec = garchspec)

# output the GARCH estimated parameters
garchcoef <- coef(sp100Fit)
garchcoef

# assume the initial conditional variance = stationary level i.e, sqrt(h_1) = Sigma
h_1 <- alpha0/(1-alpha1 - beta1)

S0 <- S_over_K * K

my_BS_price <- c()

# calculate Black-Scholes prices
for (i in 1:3){
  my_BS_price <- c(my_BS_price, fOptions::GBSOption(TypeFlag="c", S=S0, X=K, Time=T2M[i], r=r, sigma=h_1, b=r)@price)
}

# create empty matricies for the standard normal random variables under Q
epsilonQ_T30 <- matrix(stats::rnorm((T2M[1]+1)*simulations, 0, 1), nrow = T2M[1]+1, ncol= simulations)
epsilonQ_T90 <- matrix(stats::rnorm((T2M[2]+1)*simulations, 0, 1), nrow = T2M[2]+1, ncol= simulations)
epsilonQ_T180 <- matrix(stats::rnorm((T2M[3]+1)*simulations, 0, 1), nrow = T2M[3]+1, ncol= simulations)

epsilonQ_T30[1,] <- 0
epsilonQ_T90[1,] <- 0
epsilonQ_T180[1,] <- 0


h_T30 <- matrix(nrow = T2M[1]+1, ncol = simulations)
h_T90 <- matrix(nrow = T2M[2]+1, ncol = simulations)
h_T180 <- matrix(nrow = T2M[3]+1, ncol = simulations)

h_T30[1,] <- h_1
h_T90[1,] <- h_1
h_T180[1,] <- h_1

# for loop to calculate the conditional variance process Eq(2) maturity 30
for (t in 2:31){
  h_T30[t, ] <- alpha0 + alpha1 * h_T30[t-1,] * (epsilonQ_T30[t-1,] - lambda)^2 + beta1 * h_T30[t-1,]
  epsilonQ_T30[t, ] <- epsilonQ_T30[t, ] * sqrt(t) + lambda * t # risk-neutral
}

# for loop to calculate the conditional variance process Eq(2) maturity 90
for (t in 2:91){
  h_T90[t, ] <- alpha0 + alpha1 * h_T90[t-1,] * (epsilonQ_T90[t-1,] - lambda)^2 + beta1 * h_T90[t-1,]
  epsilonQ_T90[t, ] <- epsilonQ_T90[t, ] * sqrt(t) + lambda * t # risk-neutral
}

# for loop to calculate the conditional variance process Eq(2) maturity 180
for (t in 2:181){
  h_T180[t, ] <- alpha0 + alpha1 * h_T180[t-1,] * (epsilonQ_T180[t-1,] - lambda)^2 + beta1 * h_T180[t-1,]
  epsilonQ_T180[t, ] <- epsilonQ_T180[t, ] * sqrt(t) + lambda * t # risk-neutral
}

# remove first row
h_T30 <- h_T30[-c(1), ]
h_T90 <- h_T90[-c(1), ]
h_T180 <- h_T180[-c(1), ]

epsilonQ_T30 <- epsilonQ_T30[-c(1),]
epsilonQ_T90 <- epsilonQ_T90[-c(1),]
epsilonQ_T180 <- epsilonQ_T180[-c(1),]

# calculate the exponential part in terminal value of stock Eq(3)
ST_expPart_T30 <- exp(r*T2M[1] - 0.5 * colSums(h_T30) + colSums(sqrt(h_T30)) * colSums(epsilonQ_T30))
ST_expPart_T90 <- exp(r*T2M[2] - 0.5 * colSums(h_T90) + colSums(sqrt(h_T90)) * colSums(epsilonQ_T90))
ST_expPart_T180 <- exp(r*T2M[3] - 0.5 * colSums(h_T180) + colSums(sqrt(h_T180)) * colSums(epsilonQ_T180))

# calculate the terminal value of the stock for each initial value Eq(3)
ST_T30 <- matrix(nrow = length(S0), ncol=simulations)
ST_T90 <- matrix(nrow = length(S0), ncol=simulations)
ST_T180 <- matrix(nrow = length(S0), ncol=simulations)

for(i in 1:length(S0)){
  ST_T30[i,] <- S0[i] * ST_expPart_T30
  ST_T90[i,] <- S0[i] * ST_expPart_T90
  ST_T180[i,] <- S0[i] * ST_expPart_T180
}

# calculate expectation of the discounted call option payoff
C_T30 <- c()
C_T90 <- c()
C_T180 <- c()

for(i in 1:length(S0)){
  C_T30[i] <- exp(-r*T2M[1]) * mean( pmax(ST_T30[i,] -K, 0) )
  C_T90[i] <- exp(-r*T2M[2]) * mean( pmax(ST_T90[i,] -K, 0) )
  C_T180[i] <- exp(-r*T2M[3]) * mean( pmax(ST_T180[i,] -K, 0) )
}

my_GH_price <- c(C_T30, C_T90, C_T180)

my_df <- data.frame(maturity, SK_ratio, my_BS_price, my_GH_price)
my_df
```

where
$$\xi_t = \sqrt{h_t} \varepsilon^Q_t  ;\quad \varepsilon^Q_t \sim N(0,t) \quad \mbox{under measure Q or }\quad  \varepsilon^Q_t \sim N(\lambda t,t) \quad \mbox{under measure P}$$

I have three problems.

1. I didn't get the exact estimated parameters as theirs. Is the `ugarchspec` wrong?
2. I used the author's estimated parameters to calculate option prices using Black-Scholes formula, but I didn't get the same numbers. I don't understand why the BS-price is not the same. Any idea?
3. I didn't get the same numbers as the paper for the GARCH model prices either. Is there anything wrong with how I modeled the risk-neutral dynamics of (2)?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi: I can't help but I would ask the author if the code behind his garch function could be seen because, once the results of those two calls are different, I'm pretty sure all bets, aside from black-sholes prices, are off.

Comment: @mark thank you but since it's from 1995 I think they used excel for it. I'm sure since it's old someone must have tried to get the same results somehow. I also think that maybe I'm missing something since the author have other papers where I couldn't match the BS price with theirs.

Comment: @Richard thank you for only putting "1.,2.,3." to my questions at the end and not changing anything else from my original post. Just to clarify to others that Richard didn't add anything scientific to the original post.

Comment: I'm not well versed in excel but if it is being used to estimate a garch model, I would have my doubts about the validity of the results. There were still quite a few optimization routines available back in 1995 so I stand by my recommendation to communicate with Duan. Estimating garch models is not a trivial endeavor.